# Android native build error potentially insecure [-Werror,-Wformat-security]

Tags: android, cmake, native

I am working on some Native android project with CMake. Where I am having an issue stating above error.

I have created a method for logging from c files.

```
void log_android(int prio, const char *fmt, ...) {
    if (prio >= loglevel) {
        char line[1024];
        va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr, fmt);
        vsprintf(line, fmt, argptr);
        __android_log_print(prio, TAG, line);
        va_end(argptr);
    }
}
```

While compiling this I am getting issue `String is not String literal` on `__android_log_print(prio, TAG, line);` near word `line`.

It says its `potentially insecure [-Werror,-Wformat-security]`
After doing some R&D I found that I need to use certain cppFlags inside CMAKE 
`APP_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security`. But I am not certain where should I place this code inside my `CMakeLists.txt`.

I tried to use these methods inside `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(compiler_c_flags "-Wno-error=format-security")
set(compiler_cpp_flags "-Wno-error=format-security")
```

But no success please help.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I solved the issue myself. I was using

```
set(compiler_c_flags "-Wno-error=format-security")
```

instead of

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wno-error=format-security")
```

Comment: Not working for me